# Mid 2014 Macbook Pro. I think I overwrote the internal SSD with dd

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd

I was attempting to backup my SSD to an external drive in a terminal in safe mode with the following command (or so I thought)

`sudo dd if=/dev/rdisk0 of=/dev/rdisk2 bs=1m conv=noerror,sync`

It ran and I rebooted, but now when turning on, I hear the chime and the screen is on, but it's blank and none of the usual options work (Reset NVRAM, diagnostic mode, etc. all do nothing and show nothing but a black screen). The external drive is still blank so all I can think of is that I somehow reversed the if/of parameters.

What do I do now? Shouldn't I be able to at least get into BIOS (or whatever macbooks have), or diagnostic mode, even with a blank SSD?

Comment: I'd see if you can boot up via network recovery. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904  Shift-Option-⌘-R

Comment: firmware. Did you try holding down the option key then power on?  Wait 10 to 30 seconds. should bring up the startup manager.  See if an os is around.

Comment: I tried both of these things and neither does anything. Just a blank screen. I did notice that caps lock works for the first 1-2 seconds after powering on, then freezes and doesn't respond.

Comment: Drive could be good, but your logic board may not be.  Take it in for a repair price estimate.  Some places will not give back your original drive if they replace the logic board.  Has lots of youtube videos on replair https://rossmanngroup.com/ does repairs too.

Comment: It's too much of a coincidence that it immediately stopped working after using `dd`, and the drive I used `dd` on had no changes. I'm going to swap the SSD and see if that helps.

Comment: It's the drive. I removed the drive and now I'm able to get into internet recovery, diagnostics, etc. I'm going to get a USB case for the SSD and try to reformat it.